# Animation of text not working

Tags: html, css

I know there was a topic like that , but I have a problem I dont know where it comes from . so this is my code in css file :

```css
div.daymess {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah';
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  animation: dailymess 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes dailymess {
  from {
    top: 0px;
  }

  to  {
    top: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="daymess">
     Your message of the day:
</div>
```

I m trying to get a text in a div to move so here is the text and it is in my index.html . Sorry for my dumb questions , but I really need help and there is no notification or warning or error that pops out .

I was looking at tutorials and at w3schools it is typed @keyframes .... what am I getting wrong in here. I tried -webkit and -moz too , nothing helps . Event tried to run it in IE ... so desperate :D .
Is it because it is text , but the text is in a div and I m saying to move the div not the text .

Comment: add something like `position: absolute;` to `div.daymess` ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5swcnwrd/))

Comment: `top` / `bottom` / `left` / `right` properties work only when used with `relative`,  `absolute` or `fixed` positioning. Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Muhammad_Usman/7epzwum6/).

Comment: @Effe BRO/SIS Thank you soooooooooooooo much <3 . You are just great . :)

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Man thank you a lot :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change `top` attribute you need define attribute `position`. Just add
`position: absolute;` to class daymess

```css
div.daymess
    {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah';
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        animation: dailymess 5s infinite;
    }
    @keyframes dailymess
    {
        from {
            top: 0px;
        }
        to {
            top: 100vh;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="daymess">
     Your message of the day:
</div>
```

If you set position as relative, then you can change `margin-top` instead of `top`

Comment: Thank youuuuuuuuuuuuu <3 :) .